# Error while using make

Tags: make, cmake

hello i'm new to linux and currently using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.
When I performed 'make' command to install nvclock program , the terminal showed me this error:

---

```
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/backend'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/backend'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/nvcontrol'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/nvcontrol'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/gtk'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/gtk'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/qt'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src/qt'
gcc -o nvclock nvclock.c -I./backend -I./nvcontrol -I.. -lX11 -lXext  -L./backend -lbackend -L./nvcontrol -lnvcontrol

./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o): In function `NVFindDisplay':
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `XextCreateExtension'
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `XextFindDisplay'
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `XextAddDisplay'
./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o): In function`NVQueryExtension':
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o): In function `NVQueryVersion':
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o): In function `NVGetAttribute':
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o): In function `NVGetStringAttribute':
libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x5c1): undefined reference to `XMissingExtension'
./nvcontrol/libnvcontrol.a(libnvcontrol.o):libnvcontrol.c:(.text+0x843): more undefined references to `XMissingExtension' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:34: recipe for target 'nvclock' failed
make[1]: *** [nvclock] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kishor/Downloads/nvclock/src'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

Comment: This is likely a library order issue i.e. if code in `libnvcontrol` depends on symbols in `libX11` or `libXext`, then the latter libraries need to be specified to the *right* of the former i.e. `-L./nvcontrol -lnvcontrol -lX11 -lXext` or perhaps `-L./nvcontrol -lnvcontrol -lXext -lX11`

Comment: it is difficult for me understand what you are saying ,i'm new to linux. can you guide me step by step to solve this error

Comment: You would need to edit the `src/Makefile` (or edit `src/Makefile.in` and re-run the `./configure` script). However I'm not sure how worthwhile it will be - the project seems to have been abandoned for nearly 10 years (and graphics hardware has change a lot since then).

Answer (score 0):

nvclock wants the static libXext.a, but is asking for the dynamic one. i got it to work by adding /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a to this step and running

```
gcc -o nvclock nvclock.c -I./backend -I./nvcontrol -I.. -lX11  -lXext  -L./backend -lbackend -L./nvcontrol -lnvcontrol /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.a
```

in src/